# Spring boot 404 webservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am in the process of converting an old Spring/SOAP/Java6 program to Java 8 with Spring boot and REST and I can't make it work. I have a started with simple controllers and such and added swagger but that doesn't work either.

my application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 30001

spring:
  application:
    name: daissywebservice
  datasource:
    username: USER
    password: PW
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:serveraddress
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        show_sql: true
        #format_sql: true
  data:
    rest:
      detection-strategy: annotated
  #jackson:
      #serialization:
        #INDENT_OUTPUT: true

management:
  endpoints:
    cors:
      allowed-origins: "*"
#      allowed-methods: GET
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info, health, httptrace
```

TestController

```
package com.company.project.webservice.controllers;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Api(value = "test", description = "Actions to test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/echo/{in}")
    String echo(String in){
        return testService.echo(in);
    }
}
```

WebserviceApplication

```
package com.company.project.webservice;
@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = {
        "com.company.subpackage.location.project1"
})
public class WebserviceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebserviceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The `com.company.subpackage.location.project1` here is where the TestService is located this is also an older spring and Java project but that shouldn't matter.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>sproject-module-webservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>sproject module webservice</name>
    <description>Webservice for project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.subpackage.location.project1</groupId>
            <artifactId>sproject-module-services</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Calling `http://localhost:30001/` gives

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:30001/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

But then when I call `http://localhost:30001/swagger-ui.html` in the console I see `GET http://localhost:30001/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui 404 ()` and there is a popup like this
[image: swagger]

What do I miss that all my webservices return 404s?

Comment: Which URL are you calling ?

Comment: for instance http://localhost:30001/test/echo/test or http://localhost:30001/swagger-ui.html, I updated my question to an even longer post with the errors.

Comment: Does `http://localhost:30001/test/echo/something`  work ?

Comment: No it's a whitelabel page 'Whitelabel Error Page' I've been commenting things and removing other things but nothing seems to change it.

Comment: Any other ideas I'm literally stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, you should use the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency instead of `spring-boot-starter-rest`, if you are trying to display data on a browser.

`spring-boot-starter-rest` is useful when you need an API to connect various apps.

Comment: The front is another Java application but I'll swap it and see what it does.

Comment: Nope even worse like this my localhost:30001 fails too :p